# SpringBatch ItemWriter java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to write a `spring batch` using `SpringBoot`. At first, the program will read data from database, then write it to `.csv`format file.

This is the code I have tried

**Reader**

```
    @Bean
    public ItemReader<A> Reader() throws Exception {
        List list = new ArrayList<>();
        JdbcCursorItemReader<A> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<A>();
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        String sql = "SELECT ID AS id FROM TABLE_A ";
        list = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Mapper()); // store all retrieved data to list
        reader.setSql(sql);
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setRowMapper(new Mapper());

        if (list != null) {
            for (A c : (List<A>) list) {
                c.setId("123");  // overwrite the id
                c.setState("Active");             
            }
        }
        return reader;
    }
```

**Mapper**

```
   public class Mapper implements RowMapper<A> {

        @Override
        public A mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

            A c = new A();
            c.setId(rs.getString("id"));
    }
```

**Writer**

```
    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<A> Writer() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<A> csvFileWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        String exportFileHeader = "ID" + delimiter + "State";
        StringHeaderWriter headerWriter = new StringHeaderWriter(exportFileHeader);
        csvFileWriter.setHeaderCallback(headerWriter);
        headerWriter.checkRepository();

        String exportFilePath = "/home/xxx/Desktop/outputs/" + fileName + time() + ".csv";
        csvFileWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(exportFilePath));
        LineAggregator<A> lineAggregator = createStudentLineAggregator();
        csvFileWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
        return csvFileWriter;
    }
```

**BatchConfig**

```
  @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception { 
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Step step1() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<A, A>chunk(1)
                .reader(Reader())
                .processor(new Processor())
                .writer(Writer())
                .build();
    }
```

**Processor**

```
public class Processor implements ItemProcessor<A, A> {

    @Override
    public A process(A i) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Processing..." + i);
        return i;
    }
}
```

When I check the generated file, I can see the value id from the database, but not 123. Value for the State is also empty. How can I overwrite the mapping value?

Comment: you need a `processor` too.

Comment: @TaherKhorshidi yes I have .Post edited.

Comment: then the processor is correct place to change id

Comment: @TaherKhorshidi can you elaborate more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in spring batch reader is just responsible for reading data. if you want to manipulate data it must be done in processor. so:

```
public class Processor implements ItemProcessor<A, A> {

    @Override
    public A process(A i) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Processing..." + i);
        i.setId("123");
        i.setStatus("Active");
        return i;
    }
}
```

this part of code

```
    list = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Mapper()); // store all retrieved data to list

    if (list != null) {
        for (A c : (List<A>) list) {
            c.setId("123");  // overwrite the id
            c.setState("Active");             
        }
    }
```

actually do nothing. in `Reader()` you should just return the configured reader. you do configuration correctly by:

```
    reader.setSql(sql);
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setRowMapper(new Mapper());
```

Comment: But I want to have something like if `list! = null`, then it will only have this two `c.setId("123"); ,
            c.setState("Active");`

Comment: when you put code in processor condition `list! = null` considered implicitly. test it.

Comment: is there a way I can save all the retrieved data to list ?

Comment: yes. change `ItemProcessor<A, A>` to `ItemProcessor<List<A>,List<A>>`